# FTP per upload limit causing bottleneck / slow down

Tags: ftp

I am just starting to try to set up FTP server/clients using Filezilla. Everything seems to be working, but the Filezilla client maxes out around 200KiB/s per upload. My upload bandwidth can support 5+ simultaneous transfers at this speed. however, I would like to transfer one large 70Gb file (ideally without breaking it into smaller pieces). Is there some setting that makes a max speed per individual upload? I have tried multiple clients as well (FireFTP, CuteFTP etc.) and the same thing happens. Or is there some way to check if the ISP is causing this?

I also find strange that if I upload the file to a service like Dropbox or Google Drive, I can get speeds of about 2000KiB/s. It is only with FTP that this 200 KiB limit seems to happening.

Last- I don't believe it's an issue on the server side since I confirmed that someone else (from another computer, another IP etc.) was able to upload a single file to that server at far greater than 200KiB/s, however I have not been able to figure out what is different about their configuration.

EDIT:*************************************************************************************************
Confirmed that this doesn't happen if I tether to my phone and use that internet. So this must be an issue with ISP or Router?

EDIT 2:**********************************************************************************************
I have looked at this question/answer, but it does not solve my issue: [Why can Dropbox be super fast compared to FTP?](https://superuser.com/questions/119917/why-can-dropbox-be-super-fast-compared-to-ftp/119938). However, one additional interesting point that I noticed after reading this Q/A:
In resource monitor, I can see that dropbox achieves faster speeds by having multiple different transfers to different IPs (even though it is only file). Each individual transfer is similarly capped around 200KiB. Is it automatically breaking the file into pieces somehow?

Also, google drive does not do this, google drive just has one transfer showing up in resource monitor, and this one is achieving faster speeds (600KiB)

Comment: correct, I am using Filezilla server, but this is the first time I am setting up an FTP server - highly likely I'm making many mistakes. The os is Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard

Comment: regular, insecure FTP

Comment: This is a dedicated server that I am paying for through HostGator. I am the only one using it.

Comment: Have you checked to ensure there are not speed restrictions for this account you are using to upload? Have you checked http://www.speedtest.net/ to ensure your upload speeds here aren't the same as you see? You might need to check your router logs (SHOW LOG perhaps) and ensure there's nothing restricting speed at this level as well. Google drive and dropbox likely are not using FTP on TCP ports 20 and 21 plus applicable passive ports. What's the make and model of the routers between you and the Internet since your phone tether data connection is faster?

Comment: for speed restrictions on my account, do you mean from the ISP? For speedtest.net I can confirm that the upload speeds, comparing to the same geographic location as my remote server, are much higher than what I see on FTP (they're about equal to what I see for Dropbox uploads). I am going to follow your suggestion of looking more into the router, however I do not have the password at the moment so, that may take a while longer to get. The router I'm behind at the moment seems to be a Verizon Fios rented router, can't figure out much else from looking at it.

Comment: Router model: MI424WR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to a newer router solved this. There may have been some way to change settings on the old old router, but if there was, I never figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen ISPs throttling traffic over certain ports to discourage people from setting up servers at home on a connection meant to only carry "consumer grade" traffic, as a means to save bandwidth.

Try running the FTP server on a different port than 21, and see if it works as intended then.

Comment: I had already been running the server on a different port than that. The server is a dedicated server I am paying for through HostGator. Also, the issue seems to be on my client side at home, since someone else from another IP/computer was able to upload normally to this server.